# Create new Function in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I created a "**IF Formula**" in excel and wanted to convert that formula in function I read multiple article; but unable to convert formula into function: Formula is as follows:

```
 =IF(LEFT(L3,4)=0321," 12 - ABC type",
 IF(LEFT(L3,3)=021," 543 - XYZ type",
 IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("T56_",L3))=FALSE,MID(L3,SEARCH("T56_",L3),19),
 IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("MCW",L3))=FALSE,MID(L3,SEARCH("MCW_",L3),10),
 "Logic Missing"))))
```

I just include the 4 **IF**'s from the formula; but I have way more than 10 IF logic in the actual formula. Is there a way to create this IF formula in Function.

I already tried the below mentioned code but it gave me #VALUE! error.

```
Function AccountType(dCell As Variant) As Long
If dCell = Left(dCell, 4) = "0321" Then
 AccountType = "12 - ABC type
ElseIf dCell = Left(dCell, 3) = "021" Then
 AccountType = "543 - XYZ type"
Else
 AccountType = "Logic Missing"
        End If
End Function
```

Comment: Yes you can do this in VBA using a `UDF` that uses `IF / ELSE IF` logic to assign the output

Comment: FYI - the reason this was probably closed is that it is expected that you include your code attempt, instead of just asking for the formula to be converted to VBA.

Comment: Damn - I was literally just about to post a 'solution' (more of the shell of the UDF that would be needed)  haha @BigBen never had a question close 5 seconds before posting

Comment: @urdearboy - sometimes due to timing you can still post even after a question is closed.

Comment: They must have fixed that bug - I got a big red bar at the top saying I could no longer submit and the "Post" button was no longer clickable.

Comment: No worries - this post def should be closed given lack of attempt to what is being asked for.

Comment: @BigBen From your first comment about including example of code attempt; is very similar to what I stated in an answer I did the other day only to be censored at `https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61444175/revisions Any thoughts?

Comment: @Edward - the way I understand it, answers should be answers and nothing more... I like how you call it censoring though :-). Basically, it's a comment that, while true, is not relevant to your answer.

Comment: @urdearboy could you please check the code i updated above

Comment: You’re going to be better off posting a new question tomorrow rather waiting for this one to reopen. Make sure to share your code, what the issue is with your code (be specific), and share what you have tried to do to fix it. Feel feee to add the link to your new post in the comments here and I’ll take a look to it if someone else doesn’t get to it before me. Questions that have all the necessary information tend to get answered very fast

Comment: `If dCell = Left(dCell, 4) = "0321" Then`... that first `dCell =` should be removed. Your function should return a `String` instead of a `Long`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments stated remove the `dcell =` and make the function return a `String` instead of a `Long`. and you were missing a `"` in the third line.

```
Function AccountType(dCell As Variant) As String
    If Left(dCell, 4) = "0321" Then
        AccountType = "12 - ABC type"
    ElseIf Left(dCell, 3) = "021" Then
        AccountType = "543 - XYZ type"
    Else
        AccountType = "Logic Missing"
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: above code is working for first to IF but not working for 3 and 4 I wrote this:

ElseIf ISERROR(SEARCH("T56_",H5))=FALSE,MID(H5,SEARCH("T56_",H5),19) Then